# Multiple delimiters in SPLIT function, Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need help to divide the question available in cell A1 in Google Sheets using the SPLIT formula with the delimiters "a) ", "b) ", "c) ", "d) ", and "e) ", so that each cell of each of the subsequent columns contains an alternative, as in the example in the image below. Could someone help me, please? Thank you!

[image]

I tried using the expression =SPLIT(A1;"a) | b) | c) | d) | e)") and many other variations, but none were efficient for using multiple delimiters.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U9mDFnPKkGIxUQ7komK5Mzr0MBSITw6B2diNvs0BeE8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please share the string as text so we can copy it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U9mDFnPKkGIxUQ7komK5Mzr0MBSITw6B2diNvs0BeE8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en), like this:

```cpp
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.+\?) (a\).+) (b\).+) (c\).+) (d\).+) (e\).+)")
```